# How do biologists discover information from fossils?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, dna, palaeontology

I have a query about the study of fossils (palaeontology). Let me know about the study of fossils. How do biologist discover "DNA" information from dead and old fossils such as a dinosaur?  (answer this question in a paragraph or two)

Comment: Your question appears very broad; you can find entire books/reviews dedicated to this topic. Please narrow your question down and add sufficient details such that it is restricted to a specific issue and can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: You can give me selected knowledge

Comment: This sounds like a homework question...Please review our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question & explicitly indicate the research they've done, what they learned, and what is still confusing to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: @cell0 FYI, I rejected your proposed edit because it makes small style and grammar edits to a generally poor closed question, bumping it and adding it to the reopen queue without any improvement in substance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How biologist discover "DNA" informations from dead and oldest fossils
>   such as dinosaur.

They don't. In general fossils contain very little organic material. It's all been replaced by stone (silicates). On top of that DNA degrades over time.

There have been a [handful of cases where researchers have claimed to recover small fragments of DNA from dinosaur fossils](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/266/5188/1229), but these are disputed, and [are generally thought to be the result of contamination with human or other modern DNA](https://www.nytimes.com/1995/06/20/science/critics-see-humbler-origin-of-dinosaur-dna.html).

DNA has been recovered from some more recent fossils like Neanderthal. For such a general question a better starting place would be to read the Wikipedia article on [Ancient DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_DNA).